react-firebase-hooks issue with npm
Though I have installed react-firebase-hooks within many NextJS/React web apps by now.
I have one issue with this new built app when I want to install react-firebase-hooks.
Here is what happens :
me@My-MacBook myapp % 
me@My-MacBook myapp % npm i react-firebase-hooks
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@19.0.0-rc-fb9a90fa48-20240614
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^19.0.0-rc-65a56d0e-20241020" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@">= 16.8.0" from react-firebase-hooks@5.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-firebase-hooks
npm ERR!   react-firebase-hooks@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-22T04_31_00_245Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-10-22T04_31_00_245Z-debug-0.log
me@My-MacBook myapp % 

Can some expert help me solve this? It seems like there is some version conflict but it is not clear to me.

Retry the command with --legacy-peer-deps at the end.

@Devon. Yes ! It works.
